# How to convert a char after backslash to the "escape char"

Tags: c

My program is reading text file and converts two adjacent chars (first is backslash and the second is any) to single escape char

```
char foo(char a, char b){
    ...  // <---how to write this part?
}

expectd: foo('\\','n')->'\n'
```

I can write the equivalent code in Python3 like this:

```
tmp = bytearray([ord('\\'), ord(Char)])
Char == tmp.decode('utf-8')  # utf-8 is just python default codec, not related to the question
```

Comment: C++ does not have a library function that knows about the escape codes. You'll have to write a very simple lookup function, yourself.

Comment: You may be over-thinking this. As Sam points out,  if (a == '\\' && b == 'n') return '\n';   However what if it isn't?

Comment: What should happen if e.g. `a` is `'X'` and `b` is `'Y'` ? `foo('X','Y') -> ???`.

Comment: That `decode` produces two characters when given `tmp`; backslash followed by `n`. (That is, it does nothing, and `'\n' == tmp.decode('utf-8')` is false.)

Comment: @MichaelWalz why, that'll be `ꑭ` of course.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Or `foo('\n', ' \t')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for a matching acceptable escape character from the list of `"`, `'`, `?`, `\`, `a`, `b`, `t`, `n`, `v`, `f`, `r`

```
char ab_to_escape(char a, char b) {
  if (a == `\\`) {
    static const char *escapev = "\"\'\?\\abtnvfr";
    static const char *escapec = "\"\'\?\\\a\b\t\n\v\f\r";
    char *p = strchr(escapev, b);
    if (p == NULL || *p == '\0') {
      return b; // TBD this condition, invalid escape character found.
      // Perhaps it begins an octal (0-7) or hexadecimal (x or X) escape sequence?
      // \0 or \x42 etc.
    }
    return escapec[p - escapev];
  }
  return a;// TBD this condition
}
```

---

I think OP needs a different function though to handle all escape sequence, many of which are longer than one character after the `\\`.

```
int Decode_Escape(char *dest, const char *src) {
  int ch;
  do {
    ch = *src++;
    if (src == '\\') {
      if (simple_escape) Handle_Simple_Escape();            \\ \n \t ...
      else if (octal_escape) Handle_Octal_Escape();         \\ \0 \123
      else if (hex_escape) Handle_Hex_Escape();             \\ \x2 \XAb
      else if (universal_escape) Handle_Universal_Escape(); \\ \uABCD \U12345678
      else { Error(); return 1; }
    } else {
      *dest++ = ch;
    }
  } while (ch);
  return 0;
}
```