# Accepting \r\n input C program

Tags: c, newline, fgets, carriage-return, linefeed

I would like to ask how can I accept `\r\n` without changing it to `\\r\\n`, with `fgets`.

I want the program to translate the `\r\n` to a newline character instead of printing it as a string.

Current code:

```
char buff[1024];
printf("Msg for server: ");
memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin);
printf(buff);
```

Input:

```
test\r\ntest2
```

The output I want:

```
test
test2
```

My current output:

```
test\r\ntest2
```

Comment: You need to substitute these four characters "\r\n" for the new line character.

Comment: `fgets` doesn’t transform the input, it fills the buffer with the exact data it gets. If you want to modify the output, you’ll need to do that yourself.

Comment: You don't need to zero your buffer before using it like that. You can just let `fgets` go for it.

Comment: How do you display the output? If that's the debugger view, it will show control characters using that notation.

Comment: `accept \r\n without changing it to \r\n` is not very clear. *what* is changed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)

Comment: Jerry, when you write "Input: test\r\ntest2", is that 14 keys? `t, e, s, t, \, r, \, n, t, e, s, t, 2, enter`? If not, what?

Comment: @Rob I have read that question before, and sadly it does not answer my question.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes, I typed in that 14 keys. Apologies, I read the your question wrongly.

Comment: @wildplasser Apologies, apparently I used the wrong amount of backslash thus you only see \r\n. I have made some changes to the question.

Comment: @tadman I guess the 0 does not really affects anything, at most some computing power. I want to accept user input for a http request. 
E.g
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: Example.com\r\n\r\n

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, I am looking for how to do it. I have tried a few methods, but none of them work.

Comment: @Jerry Alright, that makes perfect sense. I misunderstood your question as being puzzled that `fgets` doesn’t perform the conversion automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OP is typing in

<kbd>\</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>\</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> and wants that changed to a line-feed.

Process the input string looking for a `\`, the start of an escape sequence.

```
if (fgets(buff, sizeof buff, stdin)) {
  char *s  = buff;
  while (*s) {
    char ch = *s++; 
    if (ch == '\\') {
      switch (*s++) {
        case 'r': ch = '\r'; break; // or skip printing this character with `continue;`
        case 'n': ch = '\n'; break; 
        case '\\': ch = '\\'; break;  // To print a single \
        default: TBD();  // More code to handle other escape sequences.
      }
    }
    putchar(ch);
  }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. I have combined part of my codes with your solution and it works. :)

Comment: @Jerry See [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41187468/2410359)

Answer (score 2):

[Edit] I now suspect OP is inputting <kbd>\</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>\</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> and not <kbd>carriage return</kbd> <kbd>line feed</kbd>.

I'll leave the below up for reference.

---

After `fgets()`, use `strcspn())`

```
if (fgets(buff, sizeof buff, stdin)) {
  buff[strcspn(buff, "\n\r")] = '\0';  // truncate string at the first of \n or \r
  puts(buff);  // Print with an appended \n
}
```

Comment: 4 characters I mean

Comment: So the OP is inputing the string "..\n\r..." and wants that changed to a newline character, is that it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229156/discussion-between-chux-reinstate-monica-and-anastaciu).

Answer (score 2):

You would need to replace de `\r\n` substring with a newline character:

[**Live demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gky4m1EFW9gfxTDW)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buff[1024];

    printf("Msg for server: ");
    fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin);

    char *substr = strstr(buff, "\\r\\n"); //finds the substring \r\n

    *substr = '\n'; //places a newline at its beginning

    while(*(++substr + 3) != '\0'){ //copies the rest of the string back 3 spaces 
        *substr = substr[3];   
    } 
    substr[-1] = '\0'; // terminates the string, let's also remove de \n at the end

    puts(buff);
}
```

Output:

```
test
test2
```

This solution will allow you to have other `\` characters or `"\n"` and `"\r"` separated substrings along the main string, if that's a concern, only that particular substring will be replaced, everything else stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

in your input string, "\r" have two characters : '\' & 'r'. but '\r' is a single character. "\r\n" is a string of 4 byte while "\r\n" is a string of 2 byte.

if you have to do this, write a string replace function before gets